# Updating MySQL Database every second

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, sql-update

I'm making an online game. I'm testing the game with 300 players now and I have a problem. I have to update about 300 rows in database every second but the update takes too long. It takes about 11143ms (11s) which is pretty much for task which must be done in less than 1s. I'm making those updates to database from JAVA. I tried with PHP already but it's the same. The update SQL query is very simple...

```
 String query5 = "UPDATE naselje SET zelezo = " + zelezo + ", zlato = " + zlato + ", les = " + les + ", hrana = " + hrana + " WHERE ID =" + ID;
```

So anyone knows how to make updates to database every second with faster performance or any other solution how to update resources for game (gold, wood, food,...)?

My configuration:

Intel Core i5 M520 2.40GHz

6 GB RAM

Comment: You should let us decide if the query is simple. How about posting it in the question?

Comment: We will need more information.  Let's start with the Java code that makes the update (include how you get the connection) and let's see the table definition too

Comment: @huMptyduMpty did you readed the question?

Comment: Which MySQL engine are you using? Did you try changing it ? Because MYISAM has table-level lock, and innodb has row-level lock which may make difference in your constant updated web app.

Comment: performance of update query is primary depending on the number of rows in that table and existence of index (clustered and non-clustered for fields to be updated) and datatype of the updating field. try to consider these parameters while tuning your update script

Comment: With 10 players it takes about 800ms. I can post all JAVA code but first I have to translate in english language. I'm using innodb.

Comment: If you want that type of concurrency, I would suggest using a memory based solution then write to MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably updating each row seperatly, you need to use [batch update](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html)

Comment: Yes. I'm updating rows with for statement.

Comment: each time you execute an update it commits and that takes time, using batch updates will commit only once and save you tons of time.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to PDO if you are not already on it, and use `transactions`. Also, restructure your tables to use InnoDB vs MyISAM.

InnoDB works better with larger tables which are frequently read/written.

This is one of the things that it was designed to handle. Multiple `SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT` statements which are very similar in style.

It is also good coding practice to use transactions when handling multiple consecutive calls of the above types.

Use this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20mysql%20pdo%20transaction&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) to learn more of PHP PDO and MySQL Transactions.

Example:

*With Transactions*

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$pdo->beginTransaction();

for ( $i = 0; $i < 1001; $i++) {
    $pdo->query("UPDATE table SET column='$var' WHERE ID = $i");
}

$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: Tnx, i'll try PDO and learn more about transactions. And yeah i'm using InnoDB.